# Blogger/blogspot template with static home page without displayed posts

Tags: google, html, website-design, blogger, theme

I am looking for a blogger template to create a website, that promote our services. I created a blogspot.com domain and I would like to use that because it is free and reliable. My problem is that I can not find any template to create a one-page "corporation/business" like presentation layout (like Karma template).
I do not want to display the blog post on the home page, only a link to the posts!

It is maybe not the right place for this, but I can not ffind any good resources. Thank You guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this page](http://www.anandz.co.in/2011/04/hide-blog-posts-from-blogger-home-page.html) it is fairly easy to alter Blogger templates to remove posts from the home page.  You simply need to edit the CSS from Dashborad => Design => Edit HTML then add this code:

```
<b:if cond="data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl">
<style type="text/css">
.post, .sidebar, #blog-pager {display:none;}
</style>
</b:if>
<b:if cond="data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl">
<style type="text/css">
body#layout .sidebar {display:inline;margin-top:200px;}
</style>
</b:if>
```

just after

```
 ]]></b:skin>
```